# Почему программа странно работает, joja должна быть по идее 20 в конце потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-threads

**Вот весь код:**
Главный класс:

```
    public class Grandest {
        public static MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyThread thread = new MyThread();
            thread.start();
            MyThreadTwo myThread = new MyThreadTwo();
            myThread.start();
            
    
        }
        
        public synchronized void fori () {
            
                int joja = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                     System.out.println("Поток:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
                     joja = joja++;
                     System.out.println(joja);
                     
              
               }
            
               
            
        }
    
    }
```

И вот два отдельных потомка Thread'а :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    Grandest grand = new Grandest();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        grand.fori();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyThreadTwo extends Thread {

     Grandest grand = new Grandest();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            grand.fori();
        }
}
```

вот что выдает золотая консоль:

```
Поток:Thread-1 0
1
Поток:Thread-1 1
1
Поток:Thread-1 2
1
Поток:Thread-1 3
1
Поток:Thread-1 4
1
Поток:Thread-1 5
1
Поток:Thread-1 6
Поток:Thread-2 0
1
Поток:Thread-2 1
1
Поток:Thread-2 2
1
Поток:Thread-2 3
1
Поток:Thread-2 4
1
Поток:Thread-2 5
1
Поток:Thread-2 6
1
Поток:Thread-2 7
1
Поток:Thread-2 8
1
Поток:Thread-2 9
1
Поток:Thread-2 10
1
1
Поток:Thread-1 7
1
Поток:Thread-1 8
1
Поток:Thread-1 9
1
Поток:Thread-1 10
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, ваша программа работает верно.

`jola` - локальная переменная метода. Она видна только в методе `fori()` и заново инициализируется каждый раз, как в метод заходит поток.

Чтобы получить на выходе число 20, сделайте `jola` статической переменной класса. Либо просто переменной класса, но тогда не создавайте для каждого потока свой экземпляр **Grandest**.

Позволю себе также несколько замечаний по коду:

*1.* Зачем вы делаете одинаковые классы **MyThread** и **MyThreadTwo**? Сделайте один, создайте два его экземпляра и запустите их:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
    MyThread thread2 = new MyThread();
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

*2.* Рекомендую не создавать **Grandest** в каждом потоке, а создать один и передать его в качестве параметра в оба потока. Тогда `jola` можно сделать не статической переменной класса, а просто переменной класса.

*3.* Удалите synchronized *(сейчас он вообще не работает, потому что у вас в каждом потоке создаётся свой экземпляр класса Grandest)*. Сделайте переменную `jola` AtomicInteger - потокобезопасная версия Integer.

Comment: спасибо большое, а почему - <<сейчас он вообще не работает, потому что у вас в каждом потоке создаётся свой экземпляр класса Grandest>. - вот это вообще происходит

Comment: @Август потому что вы создаёте несколько экземпляров Grandest. В каждом из них свой метод fori(). А был бы один на два потока - тогда блокировка работала бы. Уберите блокировку вообще. Зачем она вам нужна? Только не забудьте заменить int jola на AtimocInteger jola

Comment: ты пришествие иссоса спасимбо большое

Comment: @Август отметьте мой вопрос решением, если он решает ваш вопрос.